# How can I define $A$ in according to these demands?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm given $M\subseteq P(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$, such that $M$ is countable set.

So: $M=\{A_0 , A_1 ,A_2 , \ldots\}$  .

How can I define $A \in P(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$ so that, $\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$, $A\neq A_i$ and $(0,0)\notin A$?

---

I tried to define $A=\{v_i \mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ while:

- if $A_i=\emptyset$ so $v_i=(1,1)$.
- if from all the elements in $A_i$, the minimal coordinate in the $x$ element is equal to $0$, and the minimal coordinate in the $y$ element is bigger than $0$ so: $v_i=(1,\mathrm{minCoordinateY}-1)$.
- if from all the elements in $A_i$, the minimal coordinate in the $x$ element is bigger than $0$, and the minimal coordinate in the $y$ element is equal to $0$ so: $v_i=\mathrm{minCoordinateX}-1,1)$.
- if from all the elements in $A_i$, the minimal coordinate in the $x$ element is bigger than $0$, and the minimal coordinate in the $y$ element is bigger than $0$ so: $v_i=(\mathrm{minCoordinateX}-1,1)$.

But what can I do in the case that from all the elements in $A_i$, the minimal coordinate in the $x$ element is equal to $0$ and the minimal coordinate in the $y$ element is equal to $0$ too?

Comment: What do you mean by **define**? You mean using the axioms of ZFC set theory? If so do you consider axiom of choice?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach per [Brian M. Scott's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974363/defining-a-in-mathcalp-bbb-n-times-bbb-n-such-that-it-is-not-any-member) would be to instead simply define $A$ by

$$A := \{(1,n) \mid (1,n) \not \in A_n\}$$

This ensures that $A \ne A_i$ for every $i \in \Bbb N$ by a sort of diagonalization argument. If $(1,i) \in A_i$, then $(1,i) \not \in A$, so $A \ne A_i$, and similar occurs the other way around.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*